# Tension approaching infinity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, momentum, string

[image]

I've been trying to solve this sum, where you have to find tension as a function of angle $\theta$. The three masses are on a frictionless surface, and the middle one is given an initial velocity $u$. It's a pretty long problem, but there is one thing in my process I'm unsure about.

Let the masses be $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$ from left to right. The force on $m_2$ will be $2T \cos \theta$. Looking at $m_1$ in the frame of reference of $m_2$, it will have some velocity $v$ perpendicular to the string. Along with the tensile force, there will also be a pseudo force $2T \cos \theta$ in the downward direction. Thus, taking the component of the pseudo force in the radial direction, and writing the equation for centripetal acceleration, I get:

$$\frac {mv^2}{l} = T - 2T \cos ^2 \theta$$

$$T = -\frac {mv^2}{l \cos 2\theta}$$

But according to this equation, once the angle reduces to $45^\circ$, the tension will approach infinity. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How about showing where you got the cos(2θ).

Comment: @R.W.Bird I have edited the question to innclude the derivation

Comment: You need to show what direction you are writing the forces

Comment: " tangential to the string" pretty sure the velocity is not tangential

Comment: The velocity has to be tangential for the length of the string to remain constant, which is assumed. Note that the equations are written in the frame of reference of the central mass, which means that it is assumed to be stationary. That is why, the velocity of can only be tangential.

Comment: Well thinking of a leaning rod, like the one sliding on the wall, is the velocity of it at the part where it is attached to the wall tangential? Yet the rod preserves length. I don't think it's completely tangential.

Comment: No because both the ends are moving. Here, one end of the string is fixed, since the frame of reference is fixed to the central mass. In order to maintain the length of the string, the other mass cannot have any velocity parallel to the string.

Comment: It has no velocity parallel to string, however it is not tangential or perpendicular to the string. The velocity is at an angle with string

Comment: Is the "u" an initial velocity or a given constant velocity (maintained by an external force)?

Comment: Are these things sliding on a friction-less horizontal surface?

Comment: Working through the equations I get a singularity at $\theta = \pi/3$. Very interesting.

Comment: @R.W.Bird, $u$ is an initial velocity. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Along with the tensile force, there will also be a pseudo force $2T\cos \theta$ in the downward direction.

From the reference frame of the observer, the net force acting on $m_2$ mass is $2T\cos \theta$ in the **downwards** direction. Thus the acceleration of the block will be $2T\cos \theta \over m$ in the **downwards** direction. The pseudo force acting on $m_1$ will be $2T\cos \theta$ in **upwards** direction from the reference frame of $m_2$, and the radial component of net force will be $T(1+2\cos ^2 \theta)$ instead of $T(1-2\cos ^2 \theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is an absolute value of a tensile force. This quantity cannot be negative. Thus, your last formula cannot be right.

> Along with the tensile force, there will also be a pseudo force $2T\cos\theta$ in the downward direction.

Actually, a pseudo force $2T\cos\theta$ is directed upward. Hence, the correct form of  your second equation is
$$
\frac{mv^2}{l} = T + 2T\cos^2\theta
$$

Comment: Ohh right, i made a very idiotic mistake apparently. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Given, u, as an initial velocity, we can assume there are no external forces. Momentum and energy are conserved. Conservation of momentum gives the velocity of the center of mass as u/3. Combining this with the geometry of the system gives the x and y components of position for each of the masses in terms of  θ and t (taking the y axis in the direction of u).  Taking derivatives yields the components of velocity.  Applying conservation of energy to either the fixed or the center of mass frame yields:
$ω^2 =[(u^2)/(L^2)]/[3 – 2(sin^2θ)]$. (Where ω = dθ/dt).
Using L$ω^2$ as the centripetal acceleration in the $m_2$ system permits finding T as a function of θ and u.